# UILabel text wrong new line when has special character

Tags: ios, xcode, string, uilabel

Details of the issue :

When display text inside UILabel and almost the text fill complete line, if you add one more character with spacial character such as "ً" (check number 1) , it cuts first letter of text and put it in line alone(check number 2) and the rest of text in other line (check number 3)

Please note that the issue happening in the Facebook app and iOS note app

[image]

Comment: have you tried with [label sizeToFit];

Comment: thank you Ellen but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the linebreak mode to word wrap. 
This may help.
Another option, try using textview instead of label.

Comment: Word wrap not working but how i can add textview instead of label?